# Rowspan in Bootstrap 5 table is not working

Tags: html-table, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 table to present data (stock of parts). I have 4 different references for parts, each of them having the same RAW reference. The data is "created" by Puppeteer (web scraping).

My table code is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-responsive mt-5 caption-top">
        <caption>Carreto Louco PK6ª <%=partDataPK[3].partName.substring(11,16)%>, <%=partDataPK[6].partName.substring(10,15)%>,
            <%=partDataPK[12].partName.substring(10,15)%>, <%=partDataPK[9].partName.substring(10,15)%>
        </caption>
        <thead class="align-middle table-group-divider">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="text-center"></th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-center">PEÇA EM BRUTO</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-center">PEÇA BRACA</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-center">PEÇA NEGRA</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-center">PEÇA ACABADA</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-group-divider">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="text-center">
                    <%=partDataPK[3].partName.substring(3,17)%>
                </th>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[0].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[0].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[1].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[1].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[2].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[2].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[3].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[3].partQty%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="text-center">
                    <%=partDataPK[6].partName.substring(3,17)%>
                </th>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[0].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[0].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[4].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[4].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[5].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[5].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[6].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[6].partQty%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="text-center">
                    <%=partDataPK[12].partName.substring(3,17)%>
                </th>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[0].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[0].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[10].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[10].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[11].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[11].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[12].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[12].partQty%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="text-center">
                    <%=partDataPK[9].partName.substring(3,17)%>
                </th>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[0].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[0].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[7].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[7].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[8].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[8].partQty%>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-title="Referência: <%= partDataPK[9].ref %>">
                    <%=partDataPK[9].partQty%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Right now my table has the appearence shown in the file "Bootstrap5_table_without_rowspan" [Bootstrap5_table_without_rowspan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKLPQ.jpg)

Since the RAW part refence and, thus, quantity is the same for each of 4 references, i would like to apply `rowspan="4"`, but when i do that nothing happens.

However, if i apply `colspan="2"`, for example, it works as expected.

I am expecting to have the table with the appearence shown in the image file "Expected_Bootstrap5_table".[Expected_Bootstrap5_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBaOJ.png)

I've consulted various questions about this issue here on StackOverflow by none of the solution worked.

Can someone point me to the solution and what is preventing rowspan from working?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that each of table rows was wrapped in an individual table body element. When I removed extraneous table bodies, it worked.